# No option to make GeoPDF from layout view in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, export, pdf, mac

I'm using QGIS 3.32.3-Lima with macOS Ventura 13.5, and trying to make a GeoPDF with print layout elements -- north arrow, scale bar, anything else you'd want.

When exporting a PDF from the standard view (Project > Import/Export > Export Map to PDF), QGIS brings up a dialogue box where you can check a box to make it a geospatial PDF. But when in layout view, the only similar option I can find is Layout > Export as PDF... or just directly clicking the 'Export as PDF' icon in the toolbar. This just immediately opens a standard Mac OS pdf export window to indicate file location and name, but no qgis options like map extent, which layers to save, and most importantly for my purposes, to make it a geospatial PDF.

Is this a bug with QGIS on Mac? It seems other resources I've found say you should be given the proper dialogue regardless. I've seen some similar questions here where the issue was with Mac, but those were a couple years old, does anyone know if there's a workaround now?

Comment: In 3.26 for Windows, after you enter a file name in the file dialog, a new dialog box appears with the option for exporting a GeoPDF (as well as other options).

Answer (score 0):

As Said by @Llaves in comment when using "Layout>Export as PDF..." or after clicking on the "Export as PDF" icon in the toolbar you should get :

- a first dialog where you chose location and name of your PDF
  [image]

then, after clicking the save button, you should get

- a second dialog named "PDF Export Options" where you could set the
  output as geospatial PDF.
  [image]

This should work on macOS since QGIS version 3.16 (I'm not a mac user so I cant test).

Anyway if you are able to create a geospatial PDF from the standard view (Project > Import/Export > Export Map to PDF) this is not an OS problem and probably a bug in the layout export...